# Simulate Entity Framework's .Last() when using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

SQL server is able to translate EF `.First()` using its function `TOP(1)`. But when using Entity Framework's `.Last()` function, it throws an exception. SQL server does not recognize such functions, for obvious reasons.

I used to work it around by sorting descending and taking the first corresponding line :

```
var v = db.Table.OrderByDescending(t => t.ID).FirstOrDefault(t => t.ClientNumber == ClientNumberDetected);
```

This does it with a single query, but sorting the whole table (million rows) before querying...

**Do I have good reasons to think there will be speed issues if I abuse of this technique ?**

I thought of something similar... but it requires two query :

```
int maxID_of_Client = db.Where(t => t.ClientNumber == ClientNumberDetected).Max(t => t.ID);

var v = db.First(t => t.ID == maxID_of_Client);
```

It's consisting of retrieving the max ID of the client, then use this ID to retrieve the last line of the client.

It doesn't seems faster to query two times...

**There must be a way to optimize this and use a single query without sorting millions of datas.**

Unless there is something I don't understand, I'm probably not the first to think about this problem and I want to solve it for good !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you need `First()` or `Max()`? The `TOP 1` doesn't guarantee that it will be `Max()`

Comment: I don't think traduce means what you think it does.

Comment: @SeanLange When using entity for querying in c#, it sends a query to SQL, how do you call the fact that Entity function are transformed into SQL ?

Comment: I believe doing top 1 (aka First) and a correct sort or joining the table on itself and filtering is the way to go. Ad Traduce: compile, transpile, transform, convert?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier That's *translate*

Comment: " but sorting the whole table (million rows) before querying". Are you sure about this?

Comment: Translate perhaps? Traduce means to speak badly of or slander. It is not a common word at all and took me a bit to figure out what you were saying. :)

Comment: Fun fact: SQL Server can scan indexes in reverse, so that, if a field is indexed, `TOP(1) ORDER BY X` is just as fast as `TOP(1) ORDER BY X DESC`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Indeed. The entire premise of this question is based on false assumptions.

Comment: Ok it was translate guys, i thought it was easy to understand, I want to use .Last() but i can't because it's SQL server behind. So, what is the way to go then ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Sort descending and take the first. With correct indexes, it **doesn't** sort the *entire* table.

Comment: @spender There is no speed issues when sorting descending before using `.First()` ?

Comment: When going to SQL, without a sort, `.First` has no meaning, regardless of whether its asc or desc. There's no guarantee that results will be in any order without a sort. With correct indexes, there will be no speed issues whether you sort one way or another. The SQL optimizer should take care of it for you.

Comment: @spender So I assume the first exemple I provided is the best and only way to go ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier IMO yes. Move along :)

Comment: @spender understood ! Thanks... I don't feel like answering myself, if you want the rep or anything, my way to thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption driving this question is that result sets with no ordering clause come back from your DB in any predictable order at all.

In reality, result sets that come back from SQL have no implicit ordering and none should be assumed.

Therefore, the result of

```
db.Table.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ClientNumber == ClientNumberDetected)
```

is actually indeterminate.

*Whether you're taking first or last, without ordering it's all meaningless anyway.*

Now, what goes to SQL where you add an ordering clause to your LINQ? It will be something similar to...

```
SELECT TOP(1) something FROM somewhere WHERE foo=bar ORDER BY somevalue
```

or, in the the descending/last case

```
SELECT TOP(1) something FROM somewhere WHERE foo=bar ORDER BY somevalue DESC
```

From SQL's POV, there's no significant difference here and your DB will be optimized for this sort of query. The index can be scanned in either direction, and the cost of each query above is the same.

**TL;DR** :

```
db.Table.OrderByDescending(t => t.ID)
        .FirstOrDefault(t => t.ClientNumber == ClientNumberDetected)
```

is just fine.

Comment: Note that if you're only indexing `ID` (and/or only indexing `ClientNumber`) this is not a simple seek, as it's equivalent to `SELECT TOP(1) .. FROM Table WHERE ClientNumber = ... ORDER BY ID DESC`, which may or may not be efficient (depending on how many rows there are to scan). What is true is that `OrderByDescending` is no better (or worse) than `OrderBy` here (again, concrete running time depends on actual table contents of course).